# OpenGL Noob -> 2D Animation

Tags: opengl

I would like to move an object (I have a simple rectangle) and I would like to move it up to a specific position and back (maybe repeat forever).

I know I should have a variable in the matrix translation (gltranslate) but where/how do I make this variable and animate each frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to be certain what stage you are at but assuming you already have a rectangle drawing on screen:

Wherever you have your 'drawMyRectangle' function create these variables:

```
//Your starting position
float startPositionX;
float startPositionY;
//Your ending position
float endPositionX;
float endPositionY;
//The value that describes where in between these positions you are

float translationAlpha;
float animationDirection;
```

So fill in those values with translationAlpha starting at 0 and animatingForward at 1.

I recommend doing this next part in a separate function but you will need code that steps your animation, simply

```
void step()
{
    translationAlpha += .01 * animationDirection;//.01 is the per
    if (animationDirection > 0.0 && translationAlpha >= 1.0 ||
        animationDirection < 0.0 && translationAlpha <= 0.0) {
        animationDirection *= -1.0;
    }
}
```

It sounds like you are keeping it simple so just call that every time you draw.

So make sure you have a glPushMatrix and a glPopMatrix surrounding your draw.
after you pushMatrix and before you call your draw add:

```
glTranslate2f(startPositionX + translationAlpha * (endPositionX - startPositionX),
              startPositionY + translationAlpha * (endPositionY - startPositionY));
```

That covers a really primitive way to do what you described, also consider this pseudocode because I don't know what functions you are using and how you are handling your matrices.

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer, and feel free to comment or contact me if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a vague question, but here goes. Fundamentally, you need to store a position for the rectangle somewhere (either in the rectangle itself or elsewhere).

Each frame, you call your `Update` method to update all the objects in your animation. This should update the position of the rectangle.

Each frame, you also call your `Draw` method, which draws the rectangle in its current position (you might use `glTranslate` as part of this).

Comment: So for example, what would happen if I have to objects being animated at the same time?

Comment: Depending on how many objects you're going to have, you may want to abstract out the information about them into a class.  This class can also contain a render() function which will be responsible for altering the OpenGL matrix stack according to it's position, and then drawing to the screen.  Also in the class would be an update() function which carries out the necessary animation.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple program meant to experiment with OpenGL calls and the matrix stack, you could create a global variable to keep track of your translation.  Depending on what windowing library you're using (GLUT, Qt, etc.) you will have to provide an animation function to run each frame, which will change the translation.  It would look something like this (my example uses GLUT):

```
    void animate()
    {
        /* Add some value to your translation */
        /* Perhaps use a sinusoidal function if you want oscillating behavior */

        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
```

You would have to indicate to your windowing library that this function must be called regularly:

```
    glutIdleFunc(animate);
```

And finally, as you mentioned, you just have to call glTranslatef() and pass it your global variable (depending on what axis you want the movement) before you draw the quad.